# Angular ui-sref params in link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

in my router in Angular i have a url, but i dont know how add params to this link.

**router.js**

```
.state("support.root.gateways.invitationDetails", {
        url: "/invitations/details?invitationToken",
        templateUrl: "gateways/views/IvnitationDetails.html",
        controller: "InvitationDetailsController as ctrl",
        data: {
            title: "TITLE_GATEWAYS",
            requireLogin: true,
            roles: [
                ROLES.ROOT,
                ROLES.ADMIN,
                ROLES.SUPPORT3,
                ROLES.SUPPORT2,
                ROLES.SUPPORT1,
                ROLES.ENDUSER,
                ROLES.MAINTAINER
            ]
        }
    })
```

**View.html**

```
<td>
    <a href="" ui-sref="support.root.gateways.invitationDetails({   invitationToken:  ctrl.invitationToken})">
        {{ "INVITATIONS_DETAILS" | translate}}
    </a>
</td>
```

and **InvitationDetailsController.js**

```
angular.module("support.gateways")
    .controller("InvitationDetailsController", function(Gateways, $stateParams) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.invitationToken = $stateParams.invitationToken;
    alert($stateParams.invitationToken);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by changing url in **router.js** to:

```
url: "/invitations/details/:invitationToken"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.state('support.root.gateways.invitationDetails', {
    url: '/invitations/details?invitationToken',
    templateUrl: "'gateways/views/InvitationDetails.html',
    controller: 'InvitationDetailsController',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    params: {
      invitationToken: null
    },
    data: {
        title: 'TITLE_GATEWAYS',
        requireLogin: true,
        roles: [
            ROLES.ROOT,
            ROLES.ADMIN,
            ROLES.SUPPORT3,
            ROLES.SUPPORT2,
            ROLES.SUPPORT1,
            ROLES.ENDUSER,
            ROLES.MAINTAINER
        ]
    }
})
```

In your stateProvider's state, I changed the **controller** line and added **controllerAs**, also added the **params** line.

Then for your link, do as you had:

```
<a href="" ui-sref="support.root.gateways.invitationDetails({ invitationToken:  ctrl.invitationToken})">
  {{ "INVITATIONS_DETAILS" | translate}}
</a>
```